# Inaccurate difference operations in GEOS

Tags: python, geodjango, geos, django, differences

I've noticed large inaccuracies in the Django GEOS API's `difference` operation, see the example below.

```py
In [3]: geom1 = GEOSGeometry('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -19.51171875, 37.85750715625203 ], [ -1.9335937499999998, 27.994401411046148 ], [ 17.2265625, 37.3002752813443 ],
   ...:  [ -0.87890625, 50.84757295365389 ], [ -19.51171875, 37.85750715625203 ] ] ] }')                                                                                                 

In [4]: geom2 = GEOSGeometry('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 6.416015625, 39.232253141714885 ], [ 22.412109375, 30.977609093348686 ], [ 38.232421875, 38.8225909761771 ], [ 25
   ...: .048828125, 49.95121990866204 ], [ 6.416015625, 39.232253141714885 ] ] ] }')                                                                                                     

In [5]: geom1.overlaps(geom2)                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: True

In [6]: geom2.overlaps(geom1)                                                                                                                                                            
Out[6]: True

In [7]: geom1_diff_2 = geom1 - geom2                                                                                                                                                     

In [8]: geom1_diff_2.overlaps(geom2)                                                                                                                                                     
Out[8]: True

In [9]: geom1_diff_2.overlaps(geom1)                                                                                                                                                     
Out[9]: True

In [11]: geom1_diff_2.geojson                                                                                                                                                            
Out[11]: '{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.586150515699938, 35.53216784423411 ], [ -1.93359375, 27.994401411046148 ], [ -19.51171875, 37.857507156252026 ], [ -0.87890625, 50
```

The output of these respective polygons is shown below for reference. A pattern I've noticed is that the post-difference geometry tends to be cut off around the top and be too long around the bottom, as seen below. This leads me to believe it may be an issue with projections or transformations.

[image]
https://gist.github.com/whirish/2df0f7b715fe56e20b68a1ffbaafde70